# How do I add an imshow option when right clicking on an item in MATLAB workspace?

Tags: image, matlab, imshow

I want to add another option when right clicking on MATLAB workspace items. I would like `imshow` to also appear in the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a workaround for that. On the Plots tab, right clicking on the imshow function lets me add it to the quick access toolbar. now I simply click on the variable on workspace and then press alt + 1 and Voila ! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to dig a little more.  Those options displayed are what people frequently use when deciding to plot a 2D matrix.  If your desired option isn't there, you have to go to `Plot Catalog...` (very last option at the bottom of the pop-up menu in your image) and choose the plot you want.  In your case, you have to go to `Image Plots`, then choose the rig

Here's the window I get when I load up the `onion.png` image that's part of the image processing toolbox:

```
im = imread('onion.png');
```

[image]

The last option is `imshow`, which is what you need.  However, I think this is more invasive than just typing in `imshow(im);` or whatever the variable name is called.  You can also get MATLAB to autocomplete the variable by using <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the Command Prompt to save time.  I personally think it's more quicker to type it in rather than having to wait for the Plot Catalog window to open.... then again, that's just me.